# Why is iPhone battery percentage fluctuating at lower levels?

Tags: iphone, battery

My iPhone 4 (going on 19 months of love) has recently started having a bit of an issue knowing the percentage of its battery it has remaining.  I will be using it and it will jump from 31% to 19% and pop up that annoying "Low Battery" notification.  A few moments after I dismiss it, the percentage jumps back up to 27%. This happens at least ten times, reliably, before it starts hitting 11% and then I know it was "real" and it needs charging soon. This feels like a NiCad issue… I know we've advanced past those days.

So my question is: **how can I force a calibration of the percentage counter on iPhone 4**?  Alternatively, and I don't know that I would like this even if it is possible (I doubt it is), can I disable the "Low Battery" notification?  It is excessively annoying when it pops up ten times over the course of thirty minutes.

Comment: Token response: Have you tried backing up your iPhone and then restoring it to factory settings using iTunes? If not, try that, see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with my iPhone 6. It jumps from 26% to 1% and shuts off. Then I press the power button and it turns back on and says 18%. When I plugged it in to charge it went from 11% to 54% in a second. If you do a factory default reset it fixes the problem temporarily before it starts up again in a few days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To recalibrate your iPhones battery, you should:

1. Use the iPhone until it **shuts off** due to low battery.
2. Charge it, without interruptions, to full charge (100%).
3. Reset the iPhone by Holding **Home** and the **Power** buttons at the same time. Ignore the *Slide to Power off*,  and let the iPhone restart itself.

And for the notifications, as far as I know, no such thing can be achieved without jailbreaking. Cydia's app [LowPowerBanner](http://www.spiritjb.org/2012/02/replace-low-battery-alerts-with-banner-notification-using-lowpowerbanner.html), for instance, should do the trick, though.

Comment: To clarify: Reset iPhone while still plugged in at 100% charge, or unplug iPhone first?  I will be trying this out today and will report how well it works.

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't matter. I do it unplugged, though.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have solved the issue for me. Mine goes crazy. I just looked at it at 54%, then suddenly it went to 11%, plugged it in and it said 83%. This happens all the time regardless of use. Using a 2 yo iPhone 6.